# get data from the server using radio buttons, highcharts, vb.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net, highcharts

i have previously used highcharts to get data from the database, however because it was in a update panel, it didn't show the data.

```
<input class="test" name="ga" type="radio" value="a"> name</input>
<input class="test" name="ga" type="radio" value="b"> last</input>
<input class="test" name="ga" type="radio" value="c"> first</input>
```

using this radio, the data was working, as i called the javascript from back code of vb.net i did this by making a hidden field, and getting the dataset to an array, from there i used a Json which then called it to the hidden value and showed it on the chart. however now i need to use radio buttons to implement the chat: the following code is my radio buttons, same concept...

```
<asp:RadioButtonList RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="radioList test"
                     ID="RadioButtonList1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"
                     RepeatLayout="Flow" name="ga" type="radio">
    <asp:ListItem  Selected="True" Value="a">name</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="a">first</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="a">last</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

when i use this code, the data does not sure, when i refresh it does not get the data from the server. my javascript code is:

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    }
});

$(".test").change(function() {
    var value = this.getAttribute("value");
    while (chart.series.length > 0) {
        chart.series[0].remove(true);
    }
    if (value == 'a') {
        chart.xAxis[0].update({categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']});
        chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({ text: "name" });

        chart.addSeries({
            name: 'Rainfall11',
            type: 'column',
            data:array(comes from vb.net)       
        });      
        chart.addSeries({
            name: 'Rainfall2',
            type: 'column',
            data: array2 (comes from vb.net)              
        });                      
        chart.addSeries({
            name: 'Rainfall3',
            type: 'column',
            color: '#FFA500',  
            data: array3 (comes from vb.net)             
        });
    } else if (value == 'b') {

        chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({ text: "first" });
    } else if (value == 'c') {
           chart.addSeries({
            name: 'Rainfall5',
            type: 'column',
            data:array5          
        });
        chart.addSeries({
            name: 'Rainfall6',
            type: 'column',
            data:array6
        });
    } else {
        alert("Error!");    
    }
 });});
```

the problem is, i cannot get the data from the server, as it doesnt load it when i refresh page, it only calls it in the javascript.. i have google this, and feel it has something to do with being in a update panel, using redraw method, or using the RegisterClientScriptBlock .

this is what i got from msdn, for RegisterClientScriptBlock :

```
 Dim script As String
    script = _
    "function ToggleItem(id)" & _
    "  {" & _
    "    var elem = $get('div'+id);" & _
    "    if (elem)" & _
    "    {" & _
    "      if (elem.style.display != 'block') " & _
    "      {" & _
    "        elem.style.display = 'block';" & _
    "        elem.style.visibility = 'visible';" & _
    "      } " & _
    "      else" & _
    "      {" & _
    "        elem.style.display = 'none';" & _
    "        elem.style.visibility = 'hidden';" & _
    "      }" & _
    "    }" & _
    "  }"

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock( _
        Me, _
        GetType(Page), _
        "ToggleScript", _
        script, _
        True)
```

so is my javascript code going inside there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make one AJAX call (using jQuery's [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for example as it seems you are using it) inside the `change` handler to get the necessary data. Server-side, you'll return JSON with the array or arrays and assign it/them as required. Since you are using VB.NET, I'm guessing you are using ASP.NET so check their documentation.

Comment: i was told, using the RegisterClientScriptBlock method  in vb will work. and then using the redraw from highchrts, but changing the function of the javascript, but the problem is hows its going to be layed out

Comment: i never used an AJAX call before, but i was told it can work with RegisterClientScriptBlock

Comment: I've never used RegisterClientScriptBlock, so I can't help you with that. If've found [this](http://encosia.com/jquery-for-the-asp-net-developer/) series of posts useful in the past (I've moved to ASP.NET MVC).

Comment: you might no this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472323/use-redraw-to-get-data-from-chart-jsfiddle-provided

Comment: need to get the same data from the chart... instead of deleting the series, i need it to add data from the existing chart.. so i can call it from vb.net code

http://jsfiddle.net/VnCgx/9/

Answer (score 0):

First, try putting your javascript code inside `function pageLoad(sender, args) {}`. This will ensure that javascript code runs when partial postback completes.

Next, is your RadioButtonList inside the UpdatePanel? If not, then make AutoPostBack as False and specify it as a trigger for UpdatePanel.

Comment: in the vb code? and no, but the highchart container div is in the update panel. have a look at my eddited post

Comment: What I meant to say was that you have put your client-side code inside jQuery document.ready, shorthand of which is `$(function () {})()`. Instead, put it inside `function pageLoad(sender, args) {}`. This way your client-side code will execute everytime postback occurs. I am not talking about `RegisterClientScriptBlock` (which is used to push javascript from code-behind).  Also, have you added your radiobuttonlist as a trigger for the updatepanel?