# Use redraw to get data from chart, Jsfiddle provided

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, highcharts, jsfiddle

I want to add a redraw function on highchart to show a new set of data for a series, iv made the button but the code behind am struggling.

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<button id="button">redraw </button>
```

JS:

```
function loadA(chart) {
    chart.xAxis[0].update({
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    });
    chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({
        text: "kHw"
    });
    chart.addSeries({
        name: 'Rainfall11',
        type: 'column',
        color: '#08F',
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    });
    chart.addSeries({
        name: 'Rainfall2',
        type: 'column',
        color: '#808000',
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    });
    chart.addSeries({
        name: 'Rainfall3',
        type: 'column',
        color: '#FFA500',
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    });
}
$(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        }
    });
```

where does the redraw method go, and how would i call it to redraw new data when the button is clicked.

i now have this updated

```
function redraw() {


// Delete all the series.
while (chart.series.length > 0) {
  chart.series[0].remove(false);
}

// Add the new series.
chart.addSeries({ data: Highcharts.map(Array(12), Math.random) }, false);

// Redraw the chart.
chart.redraw();
```

However I need to get the same data from the chart; instead of deleting the series, I need it to add data from the existing chart, so I can call it from vb.net code

UPDATE FIDDLE:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VnCgx/9/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use redraw(), because addSeries() has included redraw function.

[http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of remove and add new Series, you can use setData() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData() function. If you use addSeries() you don't need to use redraw(), because addSeries() has included redraw function.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries()

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are saying that pressing the button isn't loading new series.
If that is it, then it's because you are setting up the button `click` handler inside the `change` handler. Meaning you'd have to click on B or C radion buttons before it was registered. Move it out of the `change` handler like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VnCgx/11/) and it'll work.

Comment: yeah that works, but i need it to connect it from vb.net so the data can be taken from the server, so i need to put that fuction in RegisterClientScriptBlock , any ideas how